# What is causing the black/yellow spots on my avocado tree?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, seedlings, avocado

My avocado tree (about 11 months old and started from seed) has started developing black and yellow spots on it over the past 2/3 weeks. I am unsure if it is being caused by mites, or some kind of disease. Thanks in advance to anyone who can figure it out.
[image]